# CSS flex box child container is enlarging vertically when having img tag inside

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox

I have the following html / css:

```css
.mainContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.imgContainer {
  margin: 0;
}

.imgContainer img {
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
  <figure class="imgContainer">
    <img src="src-path">
  </figure>
  <div class="content">
    <h3>Titel</h3>
    <p>Test body text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I inspect the code in the browser the `figure` tag container is vertically enlarging a bit. Why is that?

The default `display` property is `block` on the `figure` tag. When I change that to `flex`, the issue is resolved. But why is this happening and can I resolve/prevent this in another way?

Comment: It's not the `figure` tag. It's the `img` tag. By default, `img` tags are `inline` elements, so they also inherit the display model of any text/other inline elements. Change the the `img` to `display: block`; This is how you resolve the issue. I would recommend setting all `img` tags to `block` and then set any that are **actually** inline within text, to `display: inline` or `display: initial`